# Eliminate text for png files

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I dragged some small .png to my desktop.

I tried editing the background by pasting them in, but then you can not move them around etc.

Is there a way I can eliminate the text underneath them?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "I tried editing the background by pasting them in, but then you can not move them around etc."?

Comment: I opened my background picture up and copied the.png pictures onto it. @vanadium

Comment: I see. Of course, these are not functional icons on your desktop anymore.

Comment: @vanadium Yes they are not. I renamed those png files using only spaces with no file extensions. Now only the file size shows. Open to any new ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is a semi-fix that I am happy with.

I renamed the .png files using only spaces and no file extension.

So now they only show file size.

One side effect is that zip will not compress those files. I have to run Engrampa and manually add them.

[image]